# Simple slider with width 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a simple slider plugin to create a ticker bar like this:

[image]

and then changes to the next slide:

[image]

It's exactly like this "plugin" but the problem is that in my case the `width` of the slider must be `100%` of the screen (the plugin has a fixed `width` of `500px`):

http://codepen.io/zuraizm/pen/vGDHl

I tried adding `width: 100%` to the CSS `slider`, `ul` and `li` with no luck:

```
    #slider {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
      border-radius: 4px;
      width: 100% !important;
    }

    #slider ul {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 200px;
      list-style: none;
      width: 100% !important;
    }

    #slider ul li {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 500px;
      height: 300px;
      background: #ccc;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 300px;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Any ideas on how to make it work on `width:100%` like my example images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slider-elements also needs to get a width of 100%:

```
#slider {
    width: 100%;
}
```

and also:

```
#slider ul li {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Do not assign the width-value two times to the same element via css like in your entry-post. I've tried this on your fiddle and it works.

**Edit:**

And also do some adjustments on your JS, in your "fiddle" replace line 14-16 with:

```
$('#slider').css({ height: slideHeight });

$('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, height: slideHeight });

$('#slider ul li').css({ width: slideWidth });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/viBHe

Comment: I tried what you suggest but then this happens: http://imgur.com/3YoVkVp  the text gets an strange position

Comment: Yeah it looks better but now it makes and strange transition, do you know why is that? :)

Comment: Okay, have a look on this, i have done some more adjustments on your JS, now it looks fine to me: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/viBHe

Answer (score 0):

Try delete `position: relative;` for `#slider` and give him `width: 100%`, because full width taken from parent element. Element with absolute, relative, fixed positions does not have parent element. Or you can do this with JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a sliding effect you can't add `width: 100%` to the `li` elements just like that.
The javascript resizes the `UL` width to the size of all the combined slider items.
What you would have to do to make this work is to

1. You need to calculate the width the slides should be(probably the size of the browser window or the container DIV) and resize the images using javascript as well as change the `slideWidth` variable to the new width.
2. If you have a responsive layout and need the slider to be responsive as well you will have to create a function in JQuery that listens to the resize event. When the slider is resized you need to change the variable `slideWidth` to the new size of the slider.